# How to retrieve the newest record from a Firebase Application and pass to a python variable?

Tags: python, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update the variables from a FirebaseApplication object up in real-time.
But a FirebaseApplication is like a static dictionary object and the values can only be obtained by specifying the 'key' by get() method. How can I update the FirebaseApplication all the time? If each value of the firebase object is a dictionary with date/time as keys, how can I retrieve the newest values?

```
from firebase import firebase
url = "https://dw-1d-cc5-grp08.firebaseio.com/" # this is a test url
token = "yurddml214RsOPi9Ua0OhuDgeuzxm2Q7v7V6T6ZZ" #this is a test token
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication(url,token)
output_data = firebase.get('/humidity')
print(output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accessing data by key, you can order and filter data by one of its child properties. For example:

```
https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo="Yannis"
```

This URL will give you all users whose `name` property is equal to `"Rahul"`.

See the [Firebase documentation on ordering and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) for more examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Firebase functions to get it done.